# Is it possible to run a windows XP executable on windows CE?

Tags: windows

Is there any solution to run a Windows XP executable on a Windows CE or Windows Mobile Device? Actually I think it is almost impossible or at least it would be very tricky however, I have a client says that the vendor of his Windows based application declared that the app runs on Windows XP as well as Windows CE.

Is this possible? Is there any way to convert Windows XP executable (native machine code) to Windows CE (running on x86 CPU) executable?

Comment: If your application targets .net compact framework, and it does not use p/invoke (or it uses it conditionally according to the actual platform), then it might work on Windows XP as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native code won't work out the box because the Win32 and WinCE API's are similar, but quite different at the same time. Even when they overlap, WinCE expects the API to live in coredll.dll instead of system32.dll and friends.

If it's a simple app, and you know exactly what APIs are being called, you could write a wrapper coredll.dll that exposes the WinCE style APIs. There will be lots of unicode conversion involved!

If it's a .net compact framework application it will run if the app only references the parts of the API that are common to compact framework and the full .net framework.

It's possible to develop a cross-platform .net app that shares the bulk of the code, and has separate pinvoke layers for the CE and XP APIs respectively (if you are using them).

Answer (score 0):

Converting the final executable may be well-nigh impossible in some cases, but if the vendor deliberately designed it to work on both systems, then it probably does (the task would be much easier for someone who possessed the source code).